# C++ STL unordered_map iterator problem

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, unordered-map

```
class Demo {
    struct FileData {
      int size;
      BYTE* buffer;
      DWORD flags;
    };

    typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<std::wstring,FileData> FileMap;
    FileMap m_fileMap;

    void myFunc()
    {
      std::wstring name = L"TestFile.png";
      FileMap::const_iterator iter = m_fileMap.find(name);
      std::cout << iter->first;
    }
};
```

Look at the code above. My problem is how does FileMap::const_iterator works.
Does it make a copy of key(std::wstring) and value(FileData)? Or does it just holds pointers/reference to the key and value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iterators are assignable and whilst keys and values in maps must be copyable, they do not need to be assignable.

Therefore it cannot use a copy in the general case, it must hold a pointer or reference internally.

In some cases eg ints it might specialise and use copies anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is an associated container:
This means that its stores Key/Value pairs internally (refereed to as the value_type).

The iterator provided overloads the * and -> operator to give you reference to the value_type. Which is a std::pair

Thus you can try this:

```
FileMap::const_iterator iter = m_fileMap.find(name);
if (iter != m_fileMap.end())
{
    FileMap::value_type const&   value = *iter;

    FileMap::key_type   const&   key   = iter->first;  /* value.first  */
    FileMap::data_type  const&   data  = iter->second; /* value.second */

    // Alternatively:
    // Assuming this hold: typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<std::wstring,FileData> FileMap;
    std::wstring const&    key1  = iter->first;
    FileData     const&    data1 = iter->second;
}
```

Comment: Well, I know how to use them. But behind the scene, how does the iterator manager the resource? Does iter->first is a copy of a std::wstring (the key here)? Because if it does, then it will hurt performance.

Comment: @Morris: no operator -> returns a pointer to the 'value_type' which has two members (first, second). Since it is a reference to the 'value_type' no key is copied ( unless YOU explicitly make a copy ( eg by assigning to a variable)). PS most STL implementations are optimised so that string copying is relatively cheap.

Comment: Now I get the idea of all the stuffs. The containers store things inside them as value_types. The iterator is (like) a pointer to a value_type. So there won't be any copy involved.

Comment: @Morris: Correct. The iterator is designed to 'behave' exactly like a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee. However, there are great chances that the iterator holds pointers. If you use mutable iterators, you can modify the data, so there is no copy made, and I can't think of a reason to make copies when using the const version.

However, does you code rely on such considerations or is it just out of curiosity?

Comment: Well, actually I was just curious about how it works. So that I'll be sure that using `std::tr1::unordered_map<std::wstring,FileData> fileMap;` is efficient because it won't make copies of the key and value.

Comment: you shouldn't think to much about that. The compiler will optimize out a lot of copies. So trying to avoid copies will in many cases result in complicated code and probably slower as the compiler gets lost and won't be to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

iterator & const_iterator hold a pointer to your data. Here it should return m_fileMap.end() if your value is not found.

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_map` holds a pair of the key\value (by value), and the `const_iterator` holds a pointer to that pair. You dereference the iterator by accessing its members by ->.